# Read/write encrypted and authenticated data from/to a file in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-runtime, cryptography, windows-store-apps

I want to encrypt a file's contents in a Windows Metro application. The file in question is stored locally (LocalState folder) in the device and contains a long string that I don't want the user to be able to modify (easily). The application will most likely encrypt and decrypt the file using a symmetric key.

The protection that this provides is open to discussion, because the application can be cracked to obtain the key. Nevertheless, that is acceptable for me, as long as the user cannot directly modify/forge the file. I believe that authenticated encryption is the way to do this, but my knowledge of the topic is not exactly great.

I have spent long hours trying to encrypt a string with the Windows Metro API, using the **SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider** and **EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData** classes. Nevertheless, usage examples (from Microsoft or around the Internet) seem scarce and almost always do either simple encryption (non-authenticated) or authenticated without ever saving the data. For instance, the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.encryptedandauthenticateddata.aspx) only encrypts and decrypts data in succession. In fact, some examples generate a random key every time, which I believe I can't do.

I have something like:

```
private EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData authenticatedEncryption(string strMsg, string strKey)
{
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesGcm);
    IBuffer buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer buffKey = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    IBuffer buffNonce = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    CryptographicKey key = objAlgProv.CreateSymmetricKey(buffKey);
    EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData objEncrypted = CryptographicEngine.EncryptAndAuthenticate(key, buffMsg, buffNonce, null);
    return objEncrypted;
}
```

As you can see, I'm even using a constant nonce, which of course is not ideal, but I couldn't find another way. There might be other problems with this method that I'm not aware of.

With this encryption method in hand, I have then tried to serialize the **EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData** object with **DataContractSerializer**, with no success (objects of that class cannot be serialized), and I found no way to build an EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData object from its **AuthenticationTag** and **EncryptedData** attributes (assuming I could write those to the file).

This all means that I haven't found a way to encrypt and authenticate a string correctly, much less save the result to a file to be able to read and decrypt it later (I have another method for authenticated decryption, which uses the key and nonce in the same way).

Do you know if and how I could do this with the classes Windows Metro provides? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think there's an easier method for you to use: [DataProtectionProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx).

DataProtectionProvideris a class that Microsoft provides which symmetrically encrypts a given `byte array` or `Stream` using a key derived from the combination of the Machine Id, the User Id, and the Package Id. It is simple to use and should provide pretty good protection quite easily.

The sample docs provide a simple example:

```
public async Task<IBuffer> SampleProtectAsync(
    String strMsg,
    String strDescriptor,
    BinaryStringEncoding encoding)
{
    // Create a DataProtectionProvider object for the specified descriptor.
    DataProtectionProvider Provider = new DataProtectionProvider(strDescriptor);

    // Encode the plaintext input message to a buffer.
    encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
    IBuffer buffMsg = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strMsg, encoding);

    // Encrypt the message.
    IBuffer buffProtected = await Provider.ProtectAsync(buffMsg);

    // Execution of the SampleProtectAsync function resumes here
    // after the awaited task (Provider.ProtectAsync) completes.
    return buffProtected;
}

public async Task<String> SampleUnprotectData(
    IBuffer buffProtected,
    BinaryStringEncoding encoding)
{
    // Create a DataProtectionProvider object.
    DataProtectionProvider Provider = new DataProtectionProvider();

    // Decrypt the protected message specified on input.
    IBuffer buffUnprotected = await Provider.UnprotectAsync(buffProtected);

    // Execution of the SampleUnprotectData method resumes here
    // after the awaited task (Provider.UnprotectAsync) completes
    // Convert the unprotected message from an IBuffer object to a string.
    String strClearText = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(encoding, buffUnprotected);

    // Return the plaintext string.
    return strClearText;
}
```

In this case, `strDescriptor` describes who you want to be able to access the encrypted contents. If it's anyone on the machine, the value is `"LOCAL=machine"`. If it's just the given user, the value is `"LOCAL=user"`.

If you are using MVC or MVVM, you can easily add this to something like a `LocalStorageController` so that all of your local storage is automatically encrypted/decrypted before it leaves your app.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I have my code working now. I spent way too much time with this and there was a simpler approach after all :) Would you say that EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData is not adequate (or even possible to use) for file encryption?

Comment: Also, that sample from MSDN seems to contain a small error, as the SampleProtectAsync method overrides whatever is given as encoding, because of the line "encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8". Furthermore, one method name ends in "Async" and the other in "Data" (both should probably end in "DataAsync") but that's just me being picky ;)

Comment: Example method calls, to other people reading the comments:
`IBuffer protectedData = await SampleProtectAsync("string to encrypt", "LOCAL=machine", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);`
and
`string text = await SampleUnprotectData(protectedData, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);`.
To write and read the IBuffer data to/from a file, you can use FileIO.WriteBufferAsync and FileIO.ReadBufferAsync.

Comment: EncryptedAndAuthenticatedData *can* be used, I believe, but it requires a bit more detailed implementaiton along with pretty stringent key management. ProtectedData (DataProtectionProvider in WinRT) should be fine for what you want to use it for, and very performant.